# paragraph text caused exception findSpanStyle not implemented in this parser - Django

Tags: django, reportlab

I am trying the generate a pdf using reportlab in django. The content I am trying to print in the pdf is a rich text data which also contains footnotes. I am generating the pdf with the following function

**makepdf**

```
def generate_pdf(request,cat,id):
    
    page_width, page_height = A4
    
    page_size = A4
    
    try:
        
        citation = get_citation(cat, id)

                 
        pdf_buffer = BytesIO()
        
        # create a document template with the given title
        doc = BaseDocTemplate(pdf_buffer, pagesize=A4, title=id)
        
        # define a page template for all pages
        
        header_table_obj = HeaderContent().header(request)
        
        header_frame = Frame(0, 25.3*cm, page_width-1.8*cm, 3.1*cm, showBoundary=0, id="header")
        
        # define the content frame
        content_frame = Frame(2*cm, 2.5*cm, page_width-4*cm, page_height-4*cm-3.1*cm, showBoundary=1, id="content")
        
        page_template = PageTemplate(frames=[
            header_frame,
            content_frame,
        ])
        
        # add the page template to the document
        doc.addPageTemplates(page_template)
        
        # making the canvas
        pdf = canvas.Canvas(pdf_buffer, pagesize=A4)
        
        pdf.translate(cm,cm)
        
        # adding the pdf title
        pdf_title = f"SL-{str(citation.get('title', ''))}"
        pdf.setTitle(pdf_title)
    
        header_frame.addFromList([header_table_obj], pdf)
        
        # add your content to the content frame
        judgement_para= ContentParas().judgement_content(citation) // get the rich text data
        
        content_frame.addFromList([judgement_para], pdf)
        
        pdf.showPage()
        pdf.save()
        
        pdf_buffer.seek(0)
        
        return pdf_buffer
        
    
    except Exception as e:
        
        return str(e)
```

the judgement_content function is given below which basically styles the paragraph

```
class ContentParas:
    
    backColor='#F1F1F1'
    borderWidth=1
    borderColor="#FF0000"
    borderPadding=(1,1,1)
    fontName="Times-Roman"
    fontSize=14
    
    
    def judgement_content(self, citation):
        
        judgment_obj = citation.get('judgements', '')
        
        para_styles = ParagraphStyle("Para style",
                                    fontName=  self.fontName,
                                    # borderWidth=borderWidth,
                                    # borderColor=borderColor,
                                    fontSize=self.fontSize,
                                    leading=16,
                                    alignment=0
                                )
        

        judgement_para = Paragraph(judgment_obj,para_styles)
        
        return judgement_para
```

now whenever I am trying to generate the pdf I am getting the following error

```
paragraph text '
Leave granted.
The appeal raises the legal question of the liability towards National Calamity Contingent Duty (for short ‘NCCD’), Education Cess and Secondary & Higher Education Cess of a manufacturing establishment, which is exempted from payment of Central Excise Duty (for short ‘CENVAT’) under the Central Excise Act, 1944 (hereinafter referred to as the ‘1944 Act’).
 

 
[1] (2018) 1 SCC 105

[2] 2007 SCC OnLine Raj 365 :: (2007) 216 ELT 16

[3] (supra)

[4] (supra)

[5] 1994 Supp (3) SCC 606

[6] (1990) 4 SCC 256

[7] (supra)

[8] (supra)

[9] (supra)

[10] (supra)

' caused exception findSpanStyle not implemented in this parser
```

I do not understand what is causing this error actually and nothing is available in the docs for the same.